# C#: .ShowDialog Convention

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2010

What is the recommended way to design a new form?

Should I call `new MyForm().ShowDialog()`

or instead put the ShowDialog() instead the constructor?

```
MyForm(){
   ...
   this.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `ShowDialog()` explicitly when you want the form to be shown.

I've never seen the second convention used. It would probably also cause problems, as you wouldn't expect calling a constructor of a class to show a modal dialog on the screen. Also, if you need to set any state on the form and you can't do it in the constructor for whatever reason, you would end up showing the dialog before the form was correctly initialised.

Additionally, calling `ShowDialog()` from the constructor means that you can't get hold of the `DialogResult` return value in the code that triggers the dialog to be shown, meaning that you can't tell if the user has chosen ok/cancel/yes/no/etc...